# Hibernate asks for collections using multiple selects instead of one, how to change it?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using HIbernate 3, Oracle and Java. I have an Employee class and this mapping:

```
<set name="meetings" table="EMPLOYEE_MEETING" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
    <key column="EMPLOYEE_ID" />
    <composite-element class="EmployeeMeeting">
        <parent name="employee" />
        <many-to-one name="meeting" column="MEETING_ID" not-null="true" cascade="all"
            class="Meeting" />
        <property name="opinion" column="OPINION" />
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

There are over 100 meetings and Hibernate is using below selects over 100 of times:

    `Hibernate: select this_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE1_0_0_, this_.firstname as     firstname0_0_, this_.lastname as lastname0_0_ from EMPLOYEE this_ where this_.EMPLOYEE_ID=?
    Hibernate: select meetings0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE1_0_, meetings0_.MEETING_ID as         MEETING2_0_, meetings0_.OPINION as OPINION0_ from EMPLOYEE_MEETING meetings0_     where meetings0_.EMPLOYEE_ID=?`

Now there is a query

```
    List emps = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
    .add( Restrictions.eq("age", new Long(25)) ).list();
```

That query returns 10 employees with age 25 and performs over 100 selects which is visible in logs.

I tried to change fetch="select" to fetch="join" but there is the cartesian effect, the query will return plenty of the same employees.. Despite there is one query to database which is visible in log file, this is also wrong solution..

How to change it so thate Hibernate could retrieve the meetings collection using as little database selects as possible but still return 10 employees?

Answer (score 0):

Judicious use of `distinct` can often deal with duplicates caused by the cartesian effect, eg:

```
select distinct Employee...
```

but more generally you can deal with this by selecting into a Set rather than a List, and making sure you have a good equals() and hashCode() implementation on your `Employee` class - the Set will ensure you only get a single instance for each Employee...

Comment: Distinct should be ok, what do you mean selecting into a set? Query can return only lists, I could only do something like this: Set results = new HashSet(session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
    .add( Restrictions.eq("age", new Long(25)) ).list());

Is it what u meant?

Comment: That would work, yes, or create your own query - the important thing is that the Set takes care of duplicates for you... But use distinct if you can, that would be more efficient since the DB will do the work for you...